# WSO2 Integration Studio doesn't work on MacOS BigSur

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

After upgrade my MacBook to MacOS BigSur (11.0), WSO2 Integration Studio doesn't work anymore. After open application, the screen stay blank and when i click on any part, shows me the **java.lang.NullPointerException** error. I click on Details, but doesn't appears anything...

Someone with the same problem? Could someone help me solve it, please?

[What appears to me when opening the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNsnN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, everyone who uses MacOs BigSur has this issue because of the underlying Eclipse oxygen issues in the Studio. It has been reported in github and it seems currently there is no workaround. https://github.com/wso2/devstudio-tooling-ei/issues/1313.

You may have to wait for an update.

**Update**
The new version which works with MacOS BigSur is released now. https://github.com/wso2/integration-studio/releases/tag/v7.2.0

Answer (score 2):

Release a beta version who works on MacOS Big Sur:

https://github.com/wso2/devstudio-tooling-ei/releases/tag/v7.2.0-beta

Comment: GA release for 7.2.0 https://github.com/wso2/integration-studio/releases/tag/v7.2.0